# Clearing /var/cache

Tags: nginx, centos

I have gone through guides where it's stated that clearing the files in `/var/cache` directory is perfectly safe.

After I cleared it I experienced a backend issue. Saving configurations ended up with a server error, and didn't go through.

Stopping nginx and starting it generated an error:

Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Luckily I had a backup tarball of the `/var/cache` dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guides mean /path/to/your/store/var/cache/

eg. /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/var/cache/

NOT /var/cache on a Linux machine.  Note the starting forward slash relates to the root of the file-system.

Comment: That's how all those guides I went through stated the path. `/var/cache`.

Comment: Hi NicoX - that might well be the case, but they'll be refering to "/" being the root of your application, not the root of the machine's filesystem.  They probably also refer to directories such as /app/etc/ or /app/code/ I'd guess. Again, these are relative to your application.

Comment: Always from Magento Root. Which is either your http doc root or the subfolder off the http doc root that you installed Magento in.